# how to retrieve data form post API flutter

Tags: api, flutter, post

im beginner in flutter, i want to get data form API but the API is 'post' tipe. how to retrieve the data? please help me. thank you (:

example, i have API data "post" and the data is 'phonenumber', 'password', 'address', 'name', 'class'. how to get all of the data and show/display it all?

Answer (score 0):

I have a code snippet of it which you can refer

This is about calling the POST API of the student and pass the credentials as a body.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loginUser(String phone, String pass) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      EndPoint.Login,
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          "phonenumber": phone,
          "password": pass,
        },
      ),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    );
    var parsed = jsonDecode(response.body);
    Map<String, dynamic> authfailed = {};
    if (parsed['message'] == "Auth failed") {
      authfailed['message'] = "Auth failed";
      return authfailed;
    }
    // print(parsed);
    return parsed;
  }
```

Comment: thank you, but i want to get the data and show it in widget :(
example, API data post is 'phonenumber', 'password', 'address', 'name', 'class'. how to get all of the data?

Comment: you can use textEditinController for getting the data from the text field or use can use variable as well.

Comment: aahh i see, and how to display it?

Comment: whether you have to store the data to shared preference or hive 
OR better to call GET API of user again to get the data and store it in POJO model